# docker login returns a 404 for artifactory

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, artifactory

I have the following nginx configuration for docker repository in artfactory

```
server {
    listen 2222 ssl;

    server_name rproxy.company.com;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }

    rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/docker-dev/$1/$2;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;

    location / {
    allow all;
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://artifactory_lb;
    }
```

But docker login `rproxy.compan.com:2222` returns a 404

Here is the access log for this request

> "GET
>   /api/docker/docker-dev/v2/token?account=myUsre&client_id=docker&offline_token=true&service=rproxy.company.com%3A2222
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 473 "-" "docker/1.11.0 go/go1.5.4 git-commit/4dc5990
>   kernel/3.13.0-24-generic os/linux arch/amd64
>   UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.11.0 \x5C(linux\x5C))"

The command `curl -umyUser:myPass "https://rproxy.company.com:2222/v2/auth"`
returns the correct auth token

Also I am on Docker version 1.11 and Artifactory version 4.60. Any pointers to what I may be missing?

Does the reverse proxy also need to be configured from the web interface for docker reositories?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error, because I forgot to fill out the advanced settings of the Docker repository before I generated the Nginx configuration.

Regenerating the configuration and restarting solved it for me.